# One-to-many in a listview loads another listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, one-to-many

The goal of the simple app is to have a one-to-many relationship so that when a user clicks on one item in a list, they are taken to another list with the items associated with the clicked object.
Simplified Example: Top list would have two items: Idioms, Phrasal Verbs. When the user clicks on Idioms, they are taken to a list of idioms and when user clicks on Phrasal Verbs they are taken to a list of phrasal verbs. After reaching the list of Idioms, they can choose an idiom and it takes them to a text view which displays a definition and example.
Currently, the topic list (Idioms and Phrasal Verbs) displays properly in the ListView, but when I click on one of them the app quits and I get many errors, this is one (E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x0)
How can I get the one-to-many associated with the list item I click on? Are my intents correct?

```
<string-array name="topics">
<item>Idioms</item>
<item>Phrasal Verbs</item>

<string-array name="idioms">
    <item>Cash Chow</item>
    <item>In the Black</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="pverbs">
    <item>Back up</item>
    <item>Back down</item>
</string-array>
```

The main activity file looks like this, it is displaying properly in the emulator.

```
public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] topics = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topics);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.topic_list, topics));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    //@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Intent i = new Intent(TestActivity.this, Sublist.class);
        i.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(i);
```

The second class I created is called Sublist and this is the code I have in it.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  int arrayB = extras.getInt("position");

  String[] subtopics = getResources().getStringArray(arrayB);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.topic_list, subtopics));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What exactly happens now? Also, you're setting as the adapter of the list, in the second class, a String from the resources?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I would suggest you put anything which is related, together in one array like this:

```
<string-array name="idioms">
    <item>CashCow</item>
    <item>In the Black</item>
</string-array>
```

after that you make your List displaying like normal. in the `OnClick` you can then use the same Adapter, but update his data.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    int textId = R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID;
    String[] data;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        data = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.idioms);
        break;

    case 1:
        data = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.phrasal_verbs);
                    break;
    default:
        data = someFallback;
        break;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, textId, data);
    mListView.setAdapter(aa);
    mListView.postInvalidate();
}
```

Comment: Rafael, thanks for the help, it put me on the right track. I had to go and create a new project because there were actually several other things wrong with the previous code.
I have encountered one more error though, it is with mListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
Eclipse gives me the error: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListView
I am not sure of how to fix this, if possible might you provide some advice? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, my Mistake. This method belongs to ArrayAdapter, and should not be nessesary, if you set another Adapter to ListView. If nothing changes after switching Adapters, try to call `mListView.postInvalidate()`

Comment: Rafael, I have taken a different approach because I would like to maybe make the lists bigger, so I thought it would be better using an intent. I have edited the code on my original post, could you please see what I am doing wrong? Things work well until I click on one of the list items, 'idioms' or 'phrasal verbs'. Any suggestions?

Comment: shure I know whats going wrong. You store a position inside your intent, in your case values differ from [0..n]. After that, you try to get the Array `getResources().getStringArray(arrayB);` but android probably won't find an String array for 0 or 1... try it like this: `int[] arrayIds = new int[]{R.id.topics, R.id.idioms, R.id.pverbs};` and fetch your int like this `getResources().getStringArray(arrayIds[arrayB]);`. Also consider to accept this answer, as it actually answers your first question. If you have another one, post another question...